# Return value of type_info of typeid

Tags: c++

I'm learning how to use typeid and type_info. So I entered the code in my textbook and find the output is different from what's in the textbook. I don't know where the problem is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class Base{

public:

    virtual ~Base() {}

};

class Derived:public Base {};

void fun(Base *b)
{
    const type_info& info1=typeid(b);
    const type_info& info2=typeid(*b);
    cout<<"typeid(b):"<<info1.name()<<endl;
    cout<<"typeid(*b):"<<info2.name()<<endl;
    if(info2==typeid(Base)) 
        cout<<"A base class!"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Base b;
    fun(&b);
    Derived d;
    fun(&d);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect it to give me result:

```
typeid(b):class Base*
typeid(*b):class Base
A base class!
typeid(b):class Base*
typeid(*b):class Derived
```

But actually I got the result as follows:

```
typeid(b):P4Base
typeid(*b):4Base
A base class!
typeid(b):P4Base
typeid(*b):7Derived
```

Comment: What `name()` returns is up to the implementation. Many implementations return the mangled name.

Comment: in addition to @T.C. comment: and what's even worse, the mangling may be different in different versions of a compiler. See [this documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) to get an idea how to deal with it